# Interchange order of summation (2-star graph)

Tags: graph-theory, summation

I have a simple graph of $n$ vertices with adjacency matrix $adj(G_n) = ((y_{i,j}))$. I am count the number of 2-stars in the graphs. For that I have

$$
\mathop{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n}_{i\neq j\neq k} y_{i,j}\cdot y_{j,k}
$$

I have this identity
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mathop{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n}_{i\neq j\neq k} y_{i,j}\cdot y_{j,k} = \mathop{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n}_{i< j< k} \big[y_{j,i}\cdot y_{i,k}+y_{k,j}\cdot y_{j,i}+y_{j,k}\cdot y_{k,i}\big]
$$

I strated from the LHS and tried to show the RHS. But I stuck in the following step after several break up the sums. I want to show that

$$
\mathop{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n}_{i<j>k} y_{i,j}\cdot y_{j,k}=  \mathop{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n}_{k<i<j}y_{i,j}\cdot y_{j,k} + \mathop{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n}_{i<k<j}y_{i,j}\cdot y_{j,k}
$$

Any kind of help is appriciated.

**I tried in this way:**

$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\sum_{k=1}^{j-1} y_{i,j}\cdot y_{j,k} = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} y_{i,j}\cdot y_{j,k} + \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\sum_{k=i+1}^{j-1} y_{i,j}\cdot y_{j,k}
$$

First term is okay (that is what I want) but I am doubted about the second term in the above expression whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer, but too long for a comment.** I haven’t seen a triple summation with restrictions in a while, so the notation actually confuses me, specially the “$i<j>k$” part.

By the looks of the identity you are given, they are taking half the cube $\{1,\ldots,n\}^3$ over which they are adding some function of the indexes $f(i,j,k)$, then spliting it into three symmetrical parts, over one of which they are adding $f(j,i,k) +f(k,j,i) +f(j,k,i)$. (Think of it as spliting this 2-D integral $$\int^1_0 \int^1_0 f(x,y) \;{\rm d}y\;{\rm d}x = \int^1_0 \int^x_0 \big(f(x,y)+f(y,x)\big)\;{\rm d}y\;{\rm d}x,$$ but in 3-D.)

This isn’t a rigorous proof, but in order to convince myself, I’d write a code to see if both sides of the identity are adding the correct terms for several values of $n$.

Comment: If you see the LHS of "I tried in this way" you get the meaning of "$i<j>k$". I hope this will help.